# How to call a Rust struct's method from C using FFI?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I am trying to call a public function (located inside a Rust struct's impl block) from a C program using the FFI. Calling regular `pub fn`s has not been too much trouble, but I am trying to call a `pub fn` from inside a `struct`'s `impl` block, and not finding the right syntax to expose/call it. Surely this is possible, right?

#### lib.rs

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    var: i32,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn new() -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct { var: 99 }
}

#[no_mangle]
impl MyStruct {
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn print_hellow(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.var);
    }
}
```

#### main.c

```c
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int var;
} MyStruct;
extern MyStruct new (void);
extern void print_hellow(MyStruct);

int main()
{
    MyStruct instance1;
    MyStruct instance2 = new ();

    printf("Instance1 var:%d\n", instance1.var);
    /// successfully prints the uninitialized 'var'
    
    printf("Instance2 var:%d\n", instance2.var);
    /// successfully prints the initialized 'var'
    
    print_hellow(instance1);
    /// fails to link during compilation

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Surely this is possible, right?* -- I don't see why it should be; the notion of an object with methods doesn't really exist in the `"C"` ABI. I'm kind of surprised you don't get an error just from putting `#[no_mangle]` on a method.

Comment: (Note that `extern void print_hellow(MyStruct);` and `extern "C" fn print_hellow(&self)` are at odds, anyway -- they don't accept the same type.)

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You have to expose a function, similar like `fn print_hellow(*MyStruct)` and then you can "map that" to the member function of `MyStruct`.

Comment: This has been my fall-back work around, but I've been hoping for more. Thanks. If this truly is the best answer, make it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You will need to write shim functions for every method you wish to access:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn my_struct_print_hellow(me: *const MyStruct) {
    let me = &*me;
    me.print_hellow();
}
```

See also:

- [Using Rust objects from other languages](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/) (disclaimer: I am the primary maintainer)

Comment: I like the write-up too

Comment: Started making a tool for FFI codegen :) https://github.com/ogxd/ffidji